# Program prints the backward version of the given set of words

Tags: c

First I should enter the number of words I am going to print backwards, then enter those words and program should print them line by line backwards, for example:

3

Something

written

backwards

**program prints:**

gnihtemoS

nettirw

sdrawkcab

This is a piece of code I wrote, I don't really know why it doesn't work. I'm totally newbie in programming, thanks for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    int i, j, n;
    char str[100]="\0";
    char buff[100];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter String\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=n; i++)
    {            
        fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);
        strcat(str, buff);
    }

    printf("\nString in Reverse Order\n");

    i = 0;
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n')
        {   
            for(j = i - 1; j >= 0 && str[j] != ' '; j--)
                printf("%c", str[j]);  
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n"); 
    return 0;   
}
```

For this input:

3

Enter String

string

written

backwards

this is output:

String in Reverse Order

gnirts

nettirw

gnirts

sdrawkcab

nettirw

gnirts

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is not a valid problem statement. Can you elaborate? What output are you getting? What have you tried as far as debugging goes?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the output you get into the question.

Comment: you can start by initializing your variables e.g. "str" otherwise there will be garbage in it. strcat just searches the buffer and looks for the first \0 so that will not go well

Comment: The content of `str` is indetermined and using it causes undedined behaviour: `strcat(str, buff);`

Comment: Ok, after I initialized "str" with "\0" it stopped throwing garbage but the output is multiplied , I edited post with an example

Comment: You can find many (maybe too many) similar questions by searching: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+reverse+words

Comment: I searched ofc for an answer on stack but my real problem is not how to reverse a word but more about how to properly arrange the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got there and now program is working perfectly. Thanks for tips!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    int i, j, n;
    char str[100]="\0";
    char buff[100];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter String\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=n; i++)
    {            
        fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);
        strcat(str, buff);
    }

    printf("\nString in Reverse Order\n");

    i = 0;
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n')
        {   
            for(j = i - 1; j >= 0 && str[j] != ' ' && str[j] != '\n'; j--)
                printf("%c", str[j]);  
            printf("\n");
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n"); 
    return 0;   
}
```